# How to prevent vinagre process Ctrl key?

Tags: remote-desktop, 21.10, vinagre

When I am using Ubuntu's **Remote Desktop Viewer** (`vinagre`), I generally open a `gnome-terminal` on the remote server. While using the terminal, I want to have access to all <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+*key* combinations. However, `vinagre` processes some combinations locally, for example; if a press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd>, my remote desktop session is terminated; if I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>, it tries to add a "bookmark".

I do not want the key combinations to be processed by `vinagre`, but just sent to the remote session as they are. `vinagre` does not have any configuration option.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that the **View** → **Keyboard shortcuts** was the option I needed.

I am sorry for posting such a silly question, but I think `vinagre` desperately needs some user interface improvements. It seems that it has not been updated for ten years.